# Applying Radon-Nikodym Theorem to Rewrite a Path Integral

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, radon-nikodym

I'm working on a problem involving a path integral of the form:

$$N = \int X(\omega) dP(\omega).$$

Here, $\omega$ represents sawtooth-shaped paths going from time $0$ to $t$, and each tooth of the sawtooth reaches a height that is independent of the rest of the path. The value of $X$ is multiplicative on the values of the teeth in the sawtooth path, i.e.,

$$X(\omega) = \prod_i X(\omega_i),$$

where $\omega_i$ is the height of the $i$-th tooth of the sawtooth path. The measure $P$ is a path measure on the space of sawtooth paths.

Let p be time-average point measure.:
$$p(x)=\frac{1}{t}\int_0^{t} \delta(x-\omega(u))du$$

I believe that given the conditions on the paths, I can relate the function $X(\omega)$ to a function $Y(p)$ and the measures $dP(\omega)$ to $g(p)dp$. Specifically, I would like to set

$$X(\omega) = Y(p) \quad \text{and} \quad dP(\omega) = g(p) dp.$$

With these relations, I can rewrite the path integral as

$$N = \int X(\omega) dP(\omega) = \int Y(p) g(p) dp.$$

**My question is:**
Is this an appropriate application of the Radon-Nikodym theorem? To apply the Radon-Nikodym theorem I want the same event space for P and p. I think it would it be appropriate to say the event space is the probability a tooth obtains a particular value along the path. I believe this is kosher because my teeth are independent, but I'm unsure.

**Bonus:**
This probability theory language seems uncommon for the treatment of path integrals. Are there references for this probability theory treatment of paths? Alternatively, is there a good reason this language is not used for path-integrals?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by path integral? For me, a path integral is the integral of a (real or complex valued) function along a path, but that doesn't seem to be what you mean. Also, to use Radon-Nikodym, you would need to show absolute continuity. Do you have that?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I apologize for any confusion. By "path integral," I mean the integral of a function, $X(\omega)$, along piece-wise linear paths resembling a sawtooth wave. $X(\omega)$ is multiplicative on the height of each 'tooth'. I believe the Radon-Nikodym conditions are satisfied, as the time-average point measure assigns weight to all attainable path values, making the measure $P$ absolutely continuous with respect to the time average point measure $p$.

Comment: So $\omega$ is a path, say from 0 to 1 with values in $\mathbb R$, which is continuous piecewise affine ("tooth saw"), right?

Comment: That is correct. Specifically, the derivative of the path is 1 at all but a countable set of discontinuities. Additionally, each 'tooth' starts at a value of 0.

Comment: Do you have additional information about $P$? Concerning the absolute continuity. I am asking for the following reason. You might write the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ as $\int_0^1 \delta(x) dx$. But you would agree that, for example, $\delta(0)$ is not absolutely continuous w.r.t. Lebesgue, right?

Comment: Let's consider the case where $P(\omega) = \prod_i G(\omega_i)$, with $G$ being a Gaussian distribution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145449/discussion-between-mathbath-and-mushu-nrek).